# Original source of "Hero's Journey," and related writing tropes?

Tags: resources, tropes

Where can I find the basic texts on a story theory - books or things like that that discuss ideas like the "Chosen One" and the "Hero's Journey"?

Comment: As well as the rabbit-hole that is the site itself TVTropes also has page collecting various [books](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BooksOnTrope) on tropes.

Comment: perhaps tvtropes is what your looking for. https://tvtropes.org/

Comment: If you want a book, "Hero with a Thousand Faces" is a classic exploration of the meta-myth of Heroic Epics.

Comment: Does anyone know what the downvotes are for? I'd like to know so I can help rather than just receiving blind, unexplained downvotes

Answer (score 4):

The basic source work for the Hero's Journey, as we typically think of it (including the trope of the Chosen One), is Joseph Campbell's seminal survey of world myths, *The Hero With a Thousand Faces.* However, it's not the easiest text to get into, and a lot of it won't be applicable to your interests. If you're looking for a simplified version, aimed at writers, Christopher Voegler's *The Writer's Journey* is your best bet.